# Reflect nested categories in appearance > menus

Tags: categories, menus, woocommerce-offtopic

Anyone know why my categories stop being nested in the product categories widget within appearance > menus? They begin nested, but stop after Age 4 to 6.

I have a set of woocommerce product categories that follow a parent child structure. In the image below, I have a parent category of English Workbooks with child categories of Grammar, Spelling etc. I want to build a menu from my woocommerce categories. To do this, i have created a menu and want to now select woocommerce product categories from the left under "Appearance > Menus". Because i have them all organised in a parent -> child format, when i open the product categories list, the parent > child structure stops working after "Age 4 to 6" and turn into a flat list start "English, Maths, English, Maths etc,etc". This makes it impossible to select the correct categories as i dont know which ones to select.

How do i make the product categories selector in appearance > menus match the parent > child structure i have defined in my product categories?

[image: Appearance > Menus Product Categories]

Comment: did you found some workaround this? I am having the same issue in wordpress v4.7.4

Comment: Can you confirm you get this issue only to the **WooCommerce** categories and not to the **WP Post** categories?

Comment: Also, could you screenshot the HTML source of the menu? This might be revelator.

Comment: Also, can you make more clear in your question, are these "English", "Maths" category names duplications intended or it's part of the issue?

Comment: And are you getting this issue since a specific WP or WooCommerce update? If so which one? Which version of WC and WP are you on?

Comment: All this make me think that your "question" may fit better a [WooCommerce ticket](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/new) or a [WordPress ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/newticket).

Comment: @ClemC, this is an issue with all WP hierarchies in the Appearance > Menus, I for example have this problem with nested Custom Post Types. It still repros on WP 4.8 and it seems the issue is at least 7 years old :( I've posted a workaround I found on a WP issue thread.

Note: I placed the bounty on this (older) question

Comment: I've dug through the source code, I think I may have a simpler solution :)

Comment: ...aaaand it works!

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be a [long-standing issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18282). [This plugin](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/18282/preserve-page-and-taxonomy-hierarchy.php) seems to do the trick.

I've also found an alternative solution (which [I've posted in the thread](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18282#comment:51)). Reproduced below:

```
<?php
  add_filter( 'nav_menu_meta_box_object', 'disable_pagination_in_menu_meta_box', 9 );

  function disable_pagination_in_menu_meta_box($obj) {
    $obj->_default_query = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    return $obj;
  }
?>
```

**Update:** Needs to be added with priority 9 to work well with the default filter `_wp_nav_menu_meta_box_object`