# Hook for number of items in Appearance > Menus > CustomPostType > View All

Tags: menus, admin, hooks

I wonder if this problem:
[Reflect nested categories in appearance > menus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/260581/reflect-nested-categories-in-appearance-menus)

is caused by the fact that the parent page is on a different "query page" than its children, and WP reverts to a flat list.

To test this hypothesis, can you let me know if the number of items to show per page in Custom Post Type > View All can be controlled via a hook?

[image: view all]

Answer (score 1):

Traced down this [long-standing issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18282). [This plugin](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/18282/preserve-page-and-taxonomy-hierarchy.php) seems to fix the problem by removing pagination altogether.